# Prevent User from updating Name as blank or spaces in php

Tags: php

Here is my PHP

```
if ($_POST['name']){
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $uid = $user['id'];
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = "UPDATE accounts SET Name='$name' WHERE id='$uid'";

    // Prepare statement
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    // execute the query
    $stmt->execute();

    // echo a message to say the UPDATE succeeded
    echo '<div style="width: 98%; max-width: 98%; border: 1px solid white; background-color: orange; color: white; vertical-align: text-top; text-align: center;">Your name has been updated!</div><br>';
```

Here is the HTML

```
Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php print_r($user['Name']); ?>" /></td></tr><tr><td>
```

How can I edit this to prevent the user from submitting blank forms or just spaces? Any suggestions?

Comment: You could check if `trim($name) === ""`.

Comment: Any questions or issues with answers provided?

Answer (score 3):

First for prepared statements to be effective in stopping SQL injections they need to be parameterized. Second there are no `mysql_` functions that you should be using nor that work with PDO.

Below is the approach I would take:

```
if (!empty($_POST['name']) && !preg_match('/^\s*$/', $_POST['name'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $uid = $user['id'];
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = "UPDATE accounts SET Name=? WHERE id=?";

    // Prepare statement
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    // execute the query
    $stmt->execute(array($name, $id));

    // echo a message to say the UPDATE succeeded
    echo '<div style="width: 98%; max-width: 98%; border: 1px solid white; background-color: orange; color: white; vertical-align: text-top; text-align: center;">Your name has been updated!</div><br>';
} else {
    echo 'Name is not valid';
}
```

Also where is `$user` set, should that be `$_POST`?

Comment: why was this downvoted? (earlier and now retracted).

Comment: it is a great answer i do not see why anyone would down vote so i tried my best answer

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit of a code indentation freek. Nothing changed apart from the code indentation.

Comment: @RiggsFolly no objections from me. Is there a shortcut for that, do you bring the code to an text editor, or just give 5 spaces?

Comment: CTRL+K formats highlighted code i.e. it moves it over by 4 spaces. Only 4 spaces required to make it a CODE Segment

Comment: @RiggsFolly hmm when I do command + k it either indents 4 or goes back to 0, I can never get the second level indentation. I'll fiddle around a bit more on my my next answer though. Thanks.

Comment: No it wont do that, but if code is in col 20 the remove 4 spaces is quite useful, as each Command+k will remove another 4 spaces

Answer (score -2):

Here are some functions i made A while back they should help:

```
//valadations

$errors = array();


// * presence
// use trim() so empty spaces don't count
// use === to avoid false positives
// empty() would consider "0" to be empty
function has_presence($value) {
    return isset($value) && $value !== "";
}

function validate_presences($required_fields) {
  global $errors;
  foreach($required_fields as $field) {
    $value = trim($_POST[$field]);
    if (!has_presence($value)) {
        $errors[$field] = fieldname_as_text($field) . " can't be blank";
    }
  }
}

function form_errors($errors=array()) {
    $output = "";
    if (!empty($errors)) {
      $output .= "<div class=\"error\">";
      $output .= "Please fix the following errors:";
      $output .= "<ul>";
      foreach ($errors as $key => $error) {
        $output .= "<li>";
            $output .= htmlentities($error);
            $output .= "</li>";
      }
      $output .= "</ul>";
      $output .= "</div>";
    }
    return $output;
}
```

How to Use Simple Validation Example:

```
  $required_fields = array("name", "email", "username");
  validate_presences($required_fields);
```

Note: values in array are the name of the input fields

Down in Your Html you can do something like this:

```
echo form_errors($errors);
```

Note: `form_errors`  has `ul` with `li` containing validation errors

**Or**

You can use the `trim()` Function

**Here is what my approach would be**

```
if ($_POST['name']){
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $uid = $user['id'];
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
     $required_fields = array("name");
      validate_presences($required_fields);


    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    if(empty($errors)) {
    $sql = "UPDATE accounts SET Name='$name' WHERE id='$uid'";

    // Prepare statement
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    // execute the query
    $stmt->execute();

    // echo a message to say the UPDATE succeeded
    echo '<div style="width: 98%; max-width: 98%; border: 1px solid white; background-color: orange; color: white; vertical-align: text-top; text-align: center;">Your name has been updated!</div><br>';
}
```